# Is there any way to automate the building of Android and iOS app and release to Google Play and App Store?

Tags: android, ios, apk, ipa, mobile-application

I was wondering if there is any way to automate the building of apk and ipa file and publish them into Google Play or App Store?

The idea is customer will be able to change some image and content from website console then build the apk or ipa with their own changes and publish the app into Google Play or App Store by their own from the website console.

So my question is, is there any tools or techniques that can be used to build the apk or ipa from website where by customer click event, that tool or technique will perform the build using the modified source code saved in the server and also publish the app using necessary process including app signing.

I am asking this because I found some app builder websites are providing this kind of service where customer can publish their app by their own.

I have searched the web for this, and did not find anything to try.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are services for building & releasing apps automatically. A build server using the right tools can build your app and be responsible for signing & publishing to the stores. This takes a bit of time to setup properly, but once setup it shouldn't be much of a hassle.

Have a look at [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/), their service should match your needs for mobile apps and it widely adopted as a deployment solution. You can have a look at their [doc](https://docs.fastlane.tools/) on how to set it up yourself.

As to wether or not this is the proper solution for you remains discussable. If all your clients wish to do is update images & simple content, you're much better off with a [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system). This would allow your client to update all the content while the app is live. That way, you wouldn't have to push an update to the store just to change an image, and the app users won't have to update everytime (which you can never guarantee).

Comment: can i trigger the build from website. goal is my customer will publish their own app. no such indication found in the doc in quick check. if you already know it in details then please tell me if i can trigger it from website.

Comment: I'm sure you can set it up to be able to trigger from a website. Although it may take some thinkering as to how to implement this